# How to make swipable card (to the left or right) in Ionic?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a "card" can swipe to the left and right in Ionic. 
I've found a tutorial to make list-item can swipe to the left, then show the button on the right at : https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/make-list-items-swipeable-ionic-framework/1

My question is : Is it possible for us to make a 'card' can swipe to the left (and show the option button on the right) and also can swipe to the right (and show the option button on the left) ?

For my sample pen, while I work with ion-list, please [click here](http://codepen.io/harked/pen/xGXMjM)

JavaScript :

```
angular.module('navTest', ['ionic'])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
$scope.toggleLeft = function() {
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
};

// Build Mock Data
$scope.items = [
      { from: 'De gea', face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/605749112437387264/LcJGIoOC_400x400.jpg', text: 'Manchester United' },
      { from: 'Iker Casillas', face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/596339467419557888/8Ik_gZLy_400x400.jpg', text: 'Real Madrid' },
      { from: 'Thibaut Courtuis', face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/509399022797615104/_8tezi0H_400x400.jpeg', text: 'Chelsea' },
      { from: 'Manuel Neuer', face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/471230204036145152/tZzWfQxH_400x400.jpeg', text: 'Bayern Munich' },
      { from: 'Joe hart', face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/602513436069724160/6IEAKTGy_400x400.jpg', text: 'Manchester City' }
    ];

    // List Toggles
    $scope.itemClick = function() {
      console.info('itemClick');
      document.getElementById('click-notify').style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('click-notify').style.display = 'none';
      }, 500);
    };

    // Item Methods/Properties
    $scope.deleteItem = function(item, index) {
      console.log('onDelete from the "item" directive on-delete attribute. Lets not delete this item today ok!', item, index);
    };
    $scope.deleteListItem = function(item, index) {
      console.log('onDelete from the "list" on-delete attribute', item, index);
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    };
    $scope.onReorder = function(el, start, end) {
      console.log('On reorder', el, start, end);
    };

    $scope.optionButtons1 = [
      {
        text: 'Add to Wishlist',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(item, button) { alert(button.text + ' Button: ' + item.text) }
      },
      {
        text: 'Buy Now!',
        type: 'button-balanced',
        onTap: function(item, button) { alert(button.text + ' Button: ' + item.text) }
      }
    ];

    $scope.optionButtons2 = [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onTap: function() { alert('CANCEL!') }
      },
      {
        text: 'Submit',
        onTap: function() { alert('SUBMIT!') }
      }
    ];

    $scope.urlItems = [
      { text: 'Biography', icon: 'ion-person', url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Cage' },
      { text: 'Fan Club', icon: 'ion-star', url: 'http://cagealot.com/', isActive: true }
    ];

  });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure out How to make a "card" can swipe to the left and right in Ionic?

Answer (score 1):

You should just apply the card css selector to the ion-item tag (or your repeating tag). Include the ion-option button as you would normally within an ion-list. The "card" you are implementing is simply a styling trait.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="card" ng-repeat="">
    <ion-option-button></ion-option-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Regarding the swipe left to right - Currently Ionic does not support this feature, however there are people hard at work creating a PR and testing said PR to have included in future releases.

See PR [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/3948)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Vince!

Comment: No problem, click answer on this if it solved your problem (Y) @Harkedian